# How to create a license key for a website in PHP

Tags: php, license-key

sorry for my bad english!
My problem is I have to give my code for my customer but i don't want they can clone my code for multite website. How can i prevent that?

Comment: in short, you can't stop them

Comment: Can't stop them. You can use something like Zend Guard to make it a little bit tougher, but ultimately if they want to steal your source, they are going to.